# Apache Server: make a subfolder the main site for my dns.

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, server, webserver

I've created a blog, it's a homework of my web application class. The teacher asked us to host it. I'm the only one who have decided to host the server at my own PC, which is always switched on.

I'm running this server in **Windows 10**. I'm using XAMMP.

I've created a domain name at no-ip.com. After hours of fighting against the configurations, I've got the website working in my computer, in my LAN and finally, the whole Internet too.

I know the worst have been over. So it's just a silly thing I want to fix. I have my website inside this directory: C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress

If I want to access to it, I must write http://IP/DNS.ddns.net/**wordpress**

I want to get rid of the "/wordpress"
I would like to access to my website with the specific ddns I have created without having to type /wordpress at the end.

I'm sure this have a name but I can't guess it right now, and I don't know how to configure this for Windows 10. I'm still learning it in another subject, but it's for Linux and Windows Server (IIS). The most alike is Linux (Apache) but the files and directories are different.

Can you help me, please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You should set `DocumentRoot` variable][1](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) in apache to the proper path.

For example if you have

```
DocumentRoot "c:/www"
<Directory "c:/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

You should edit it to be

```
DocumentRoot "c:/www/wordpress"
<Directory "c:/www/wordpress">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And restart apache

Comment: When I try that, the page loads correctly. But the links are incorrect. I select an entry and it will keep loading http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs.ddns.net/wordpress/cepillo-selfie/ instead http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs.ddns.net/cepillo-selfie/

Comment: This is because your installation in under path `/wordpress` You can try to reconfigure it.